# How install new USB wifi adaptor to Raspberry Pi2 with Snappy Ubuntu Core

Tags: raspberrypi

I am new to ubuntu core.

I used Raspberry Pi 2 to run Ubuntu Core.
However i cannot detect my wireless USB adaptor.

How to download driver to install and config to use wifi?

thanks!

Kay Boon

Comment: not all USB adapters work with ARM architecture - what wireless adapter is it

Comment: It support by ubuntu 14.10 LTS OS and Raspberry PI NOOB OS with plug in.

How to check the device / hardware connection in Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Comment: 14.10 is well past End of Life and *no longer supported*.  NOOB OS is a modified Debian by default.  What Ubuntu do you have on your RPi2?  (I would also recommend an *actual* desktop OS rather than Core for an RPi2, if you can afford the larger memory card; MATE 15.10 works wonderfully on the RPi2)